# WPF ellipse path

Tags: wpf, path, ellipse

I am trying to move an image in wpf. 
The image should follow an ellipse as a path.
When the animation is complete, it should start again immediately.
(for example a planet makes a revolution)

If I am right i should use DoubleAnimation.

The question is what should I write to the DoubleAnimation tag.

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
    <Image Source="t:\\moon.jpg" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation>

                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [PathAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx) not DoubleAnimation.

Example From MSDN:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <MatrixAnimationUsingPath
          Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonMatrixTransform"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix"
          DoesRotateWithTangent="True"
          Duration="0:0:5" 
          RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
            <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
              <PathGeometry 
                Figures="F1 M 147.5,0.5C 228.686,0.5 294.5,24.4528 294.5,54C 294.5,83.5472 228.686,107.5 147.5,107.5C 66.3141,107.5 0.5,83.5472 0.5,54C 0.5,24.4528 66.3142,0.5 147.5,0.5 Z" 
                PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" />
            </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
          </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
```

> You can learn about *Path Markup Syntax* [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)

Comment: In PathGeometry Figures the numbers are point coordinates I suppose. But what the letters are stands for?
(M, C) ?
Furthermore this is a sine curve.

Comment: @MandyTaylor I edited my post. Don't worry about those values, they can be produced with tools like *Expression Design*